# Survey adjusted contingency table with Taylor Series linearization

Tags: c++, performance, r, statistics

I am an R programmer who is learning C++/Rcpp. I wrote some code to recreate survey adjusted contingency tables a la SAS's surveyfreq procedure using Taylor Series linearization to generate standard errors. [Here is the documentation from SAS](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_surveyfreq_details19.htm) that I used as reference.I've reached the point where I know my code is correct (the results are accurate), but I don't know how to further optimize. I suspect my code would scale to large data badly.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]


// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::uvec intersection(const arma::uvec& x_,const arma::uvec& y_) {

  std::vector<double> x(x_.begin(),x_.end()),y(y_.begin(),y_.end());

  std::sort(x.begin(),x.end());std::sort(y.begin(),y.end());

  std::vector<double> temp;

  std::set_intersection(x.begin(),x.end(),y.begin(),y.end(),std::back_inserter(temp));

  arma::uvec out=arma::conv_to<arma::uvec>::from(temp);

  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec groupSum(const arma::vec& x_,const arma::vec& group_) {

  uvec index=arma::sort_index(group_);
  vec x=x_.elem(index);
  vec group=group_.elem(index);
  std::vector<double> temp;
  int row=0;
  temp.push_back(0);
  for (int i=0;i<x.size();i++) {
    temp[row]+=x[i];
    if (group[i]!=group[i+1] && i!=(x.size()-1)) {
      row++;
      temp.push_back(0);
    }
  }
  return arma::conv_to<arma::vec>::from(temp);
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame tsTotal1(const NumericVector& value_,const  NumericVector& weight_,
             const NumericVector& strata_,const NumericVector& cluster_) {
  // calculates totals, standard errors for totals, percent, standard error for 
  // percent for one way contigency table

  // make arma vecs
  vec value(value_), weight(weight_), strata(strata_), cluster(cluster_);
  // unique levels and strata
  vec levels=unique(value);
  vec strats=unique(strata);
  // allocate memory for output
  vec totals(levels.size());
  vec variances(levels.size());
  vec percent(levels.size());
  vec percentSE(levels.size());
  vec outVal(levels.size());
  Rcpp::Rcout << "# of Strata: " << strats.size() << std::endl;

  double total=sum(weight);
  Rcpp::Rcout << "Sum of weights: " << total << std::endl;
  int totalclusters=0;
  // allocate memorey for objects in loop
  int clustnum;
  double variance,pvar,cn;
  vec clustsum, subweights, pclustsum;
  // for each level
  for (int i=0;i<levels.size();i++) {
    // total summed weight
    uvec valdelta=arma::find(value==levels[i]);
    totals[i]=sum(weight.elem(valdelta));
    percent[i]=totals[i]/total;
    outVal[i]=levels[i];
    // init variance sum
    variance=0;pvar=0;
    // for each strata
    for (int j=0;j<strats.size();j++) {
      // clusters nested in strata
      uvec stratdelta=arma::find(strata==strats[j]);
      vec subclust=unique(cluster.elem(stratdelta)); //shouldn't define vec in loop
      clustnum=subclust.size();
      if (clustnum==1) {
        continue;
      }
      totalclusters+=clustnum;
      cn=clustnum;
      clustsum.set_size(clustnum);
      pclustsum.set_size(clustnum);
      subweights.set_size(stratdelta.size());

      subweights=weight.elem(stratdelta);
      subweights.elem(arma::find(value.elem(stratdelta)!=levels[i])).zeros();
      clustsum=groupSum(subweights,cluster.elem(stratdelta));
      pclustsum=(clustsum-percent[i]*groupSum(weight.elem(stratdelta),cluster.elem(stratdelta)))/total;
      // add variance of strata j
      variance+=(cn/(cn-1))*sum(pow(clustsum-mean(clustsum),2));
      pvar+=(cn/(cn-1))*sum(pow(pclustsum-mean(pclustsum),2));
    }
    // take sqrt and append to output vec
    variances[i]=sqrt(variance);
    percentSE[i]=sqrt(pvar);
  }
  Rcpp::Rcout << "# of Clusters: " << totalclusters/levels.size() << std::endl;
  return DataFrame::create(_["values"]=outVal,
                      _["totals"]=totals,
                      _["SE"]=variances,
                      _["percent"]=percent*100,
                      _["percentSE"]=percentSE*100);
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame tsTotal2(const NumericVector& value_,const NumericVector& value2_, const  NumericVector& weight_,
                   const NumericVector& strata_,const NumericVector& cluster_) {
  // calculates totals, standard errors for totals, percent, standard error for percent
  // column and row percent and their standard errors for a two way contigency table

  // make arma vecs
  vec value(value_), value2(value2_),weight(weight_), strata(strata_), cluster(cluster_);
  // unique levels and strata
  vec levels=unique(value);
  vec levels2=unique(value2);
  vec strats=unique(strata);
  // allocate memory for output
  vec totals(levels.size()*levels2.size());
  vec variances(levels.size()*levels2.size());
  vec percent(levels.size()*levels2.size());
  vec percentSE(levels.size()*levels2.size());
  vec rpercent(levels.size()*levels2.size());
  vec rpercentSE(levels.size()*levels2.size());
  vec cpercent(levels.size()*levels2.size());
  vec cpercentSE(levels.size()*levels2.size());
  vec outVal(levels.size()*levels2.size());
  vec outVal2(levels.size()*levels2.size());
  Rcpp::Rcout << "# of Strata: " << strats.size() << std::endl;

  double total=sum(weight);
  Rcpp::Rcout << "Sum of weights: " << total << std::endl;
  int totalclusters=0;
  // allocate memorey for objects in loop
  int clustnum, count;
  double variance,pvar,rpvar,cpvar,cn,rtotal,ctotal;
  vec clustsum, subweights, pclustsum, rpclustsum,cpclustsum, rdelta, cdelta;
  // for each level
  count=0;
  for (int i=0;i<levels.size();i++) {
    for (int k=0;k<levels2.size();k++) {
      // total summed weight
      uvec valdelta1=arma::find(value==levels[i]);
      uvec valdelta2=arma::find(value2==levels2[k]);
      totals[count]=sum(weight.elem(intersection(valdelta1,valdelta2)));
      percent[count]=totals[count]/total;
      rtotal=sum(weight.elem(valdelta1));
      ctotal=sum(weight.elem(valdelta2));
      rpercent[count]=totals[count]/rtotal;
      cpercent[count]=totals[count]/ctotal;
      outVal[count]=levels[i];
      outVal2[count]=levels2[k];
      // init variance sum
      variance=0;pvar=0;rpvar=0;cpvar=0;
      // for each strata
      for (int j=0;j<strats.size();j++) {
        // clusters nested in strata
        uvec stratdelta=arma::find(strata==strats[j]);
        vec subclust=unique(cluster.elem(stratdelta)); //shouldn't define vec in loop
        clustnum=subclust.size();
        if (clustnum==1) {
          continue;
        }
        totalclusters+=clustnum;
        cn=clustnum;
        clustsum.set_size(clustnum);
        pclustsum.set_size(clustnum);
        subweights.set_size(stratdelta.size());
        rdelta.set_size(stratdelta.size());
        cdelta.set_size(stratdelta.size());

        subweights=weight.elem(stratdelta);
        subweights.elem(arma::find(value.elem(stratdelta)!=levels[i])).zeros();
        subweights.elem(arma::find(value2.elem(stratdelta)!=levels2[k])).zeros();
        clustsum=groupSum(subweights,cluster.elem(stratdelta));
        pclustsum=(clustsum-percent[count]*groupSum(weight.elem(stratdelta),cluster.elem(stratdelta)))/total;
        rdelta=weight.elem(stratdelta);
        rdelta.elem(arma::find(value.elem(stratdelta)!=levels[i])).zeros();
        cdelta=weight.elem(stratdelta);
        cdelta.elem(arma::find(value2.elem(stratdelta)!=levels2[k])).zeros();

        rpclustsum=(clustsum-rpercent[count]*groupSum(rdelta,cluster.elem(stratdelta)))/rtotal;
        cpclustsum=(clustsum-cpercent[count]*groupSum(cdelta,cluster.elem(stratdelta)))/ctotal;

        // add variance of strata j
        variance+=(cn/(cn-1))*sum(pow(clustsum-mean(clustsum),2));
        pvar+=(cn/(cn-1))*sum(pow(pclustsum-mean(pclustsum),2));
        rpvar+=(cn/(cn-1))*sum(pow(rpclustsum-mean(rpclustsum),2));
        cpvar+=(cn/(cn-1))*sum(pow(cpclustsum-mean(cpclustsum),2));
      }
      // take sqrt and append to output vec
      variances[count]=sqrt(variance);
      percentSE[count]=sqrt(pvar);
      rpercentSE[count]=sqrt(rpvar);
      cpercentSE[count]=sqrt(cpvar);
      count+=1;
    }
  }
  Rcpp::Rcout << "# of Clusters: " << totalclusters/(levels.size()*levels2.size()) << std::endl;
  return DataFrame::create(_["values"]=outVal,
                           _["byValues"]=outVal2,
                           _["totals"]=totals,
                           _["SE"]=variances,
                           _["percent"]=percent*100,
                           _["percentSE"]=percentSE*100,
                           _["colPercent"]=cpercent*100,
                           _["colPercentSE"]=cpercentSE*100,
                           _["rowPercent"]=rpercent*100,
                           _["rowPercentSE"]=rpercentSE*100);
}
```